# Prove that for continuous functions in $C[a,b]$, $\|f\|_{C}=\|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I want to proof that for continuous functions in $C[a,b]$,  $\|f\|_{C}=\|f\|_{L^\infty}=\text{ess} \sup(f)$  I saw in this post [continuity, essential supremum and supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494960/continuity-essential-supremum-and-supremum)  a different proof but for $C(\mathbb{R})$, so I wonder if my proof is OK for $C[a,b]$ and the difference is just to the fact that I can't use Weierstrass's theorem in  $C(\mathbb{R})$  ? If is not Ok, could you fixed it?

**My proof:**

The definition of $\|f\|_{L^\infty}=\text{ess} \sup(f)= \inf\{C\ge0, |f(x)|\le C \text{ for a.e  } x\}$ and $\|f(x)\|_{C}=\max_{a\le x \le b} |f(x)|$

if $f \in C[a,b]$. Then by Weierstrass's theorem $\exists m,M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m\le f(x)\le M  \forall x \in [a,b]$,

so $|f(x)|\le \max\{|M|,|m| \} = \max_{a\le x \le b} |f(x)|  \forall x \in [a,b]$

Then  $\text{ess} \sup(f)=\inf\{C\ge0, |f(x)|\le C \text{ for a.e  } x\}=\max_{a\le x \le b} |f(x)|=\|f\|_{C}$

Comment: Seems to me to be OK.

Comment: ??? ess sup is the _definition_ of $||f||_\infty$.

Comment: Note that other post claims to be a proof that ess sup = sup, which is _not_ just the definition - it does not say it's proving ess sup = $||f||_\infty$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich what about now?, I was mixing the notation with the $\infty$ subindex

Comment: It's ok now, but only because you _gave_ the definition of $||f||_{C^\infty}$; if you hadn't stated that definition nobody would ever guess that's what the notation meant. It's really an awesomely bad choice of notation, because $C^\infty$ is standard notation for a certain vector space $C^\infty$ and this notation looks like a norm defined on that space. I'd just call it $||f||_C$ (but still include the definition)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the more explicit version of Weierstrass's theorem:

$$\exists c,d\in[a,b]: \forall x\in[a,b]: f(c) \leq f(x) \leq f(d)$$

Then your proof works. Just using the existence of $m,M$ which bound $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ doesn't tell you that these are the tightest $m$ and $M$ you can find; the explicit version ensures this by saying there exists points $c$ and $d$ where these bounds are explicitly attained.